# More Efficient Code? (AVAudioPlayer)

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, avaudioplayer

In the phone below I am readying an AVAudioPlayer for four different sounds in my app. If I do not do this, it causes the app to delay about 1.5 seconds is I just do it where I need to hear it. So is there any way to make this code look better or work more efficiently because now I am readying these sounds in my App-Delegate and it slows down the launch a little bit. So here is the code and let me know if there is any way to make this code below better:

```
- (void)readySounds {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TrackUno" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
        AVAudioPlayer *one = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
        [file release];
        self.tr1 = one;
        [one release];
        [tr1 prepareToPlay];
        [tr1 setDelegate:self];

        NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TrackDos" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *file2 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path2];
        AVAudioPlayer *two = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file2 error:nil];
        [file2 release];
        self.tr2 = two;
        [two release];
        [tr2 prepareToPlay];
        [tr2 setDelegate:self];

        NSString *path3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Click" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *file3 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path3];
        AVAudioPlayer *three = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file3 error:nil];
        [file3 release];
        self.clk = three;
        [three release];
        [clk prepareToPlay];
        [clk setDelegate:self];

        NSString *path4 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HSSound" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *file4 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path4];
        AVAudioPlayer *four = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file4 error:nil];
        [file4 release];
        self.hs = four;
        [four release];
        [hs prepareToPlay];
        [hs setDelegate:self];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If initialization times are your sole concern, then you could possibly* create this on a secondary thread and improve the *perceived* launch times. It would then init the streams and decoders, and open the audio files from disk from a secondary thread.

If playback, stream count, memory usage, CPU, load times, decoding, filtering, resampling, etc. are still factors: You are using the highest level APIs, you can drop down a few levels and have all the control you want over each and every one of these aspects.

You can make it look better by refactoring it -- the method does a similar sequence four times.

---

**'possibly' because I have only used the lower level APIs, I don't know if AVAudioPlayer has threading constraints.*

---

**Example refactoring with added error checking:**

Not compiled, but you get the idea:

```
- (AVAudioPlayer *)newAudioPlayerForFile:(NSString *)fileName extension:(NSString *)extension inBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
  assert(fileName && extension && bundle);
  NSURL * url = [bundle URLForResource:fileName ofType:extension];
  if (nil == url) {
    assert(0 && "could not locate resource");
    return nil;
  }

  NSError * error = 0;
  AVAudioPlayer * spieler = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
  assert(spieler);

  if (nil != error) {
    NSLog(@"Error encountered creating audio player for file (%@): %@", fileName, error);
    [spieler release], spieler = nil;
    return nil;
  }

  [spieler prepareToPlay];
  [spieler setDelegate:self];

  return spieler;
}

- (void)readySounds
{
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
  NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  self.tr1 = [[self newAudioPlayerForFile:@"TrackUno" extension:@"mp3" inBundle:mainBundle] autorelease];
  self.tr2 = [[self newAudioPlayerForFile:@"TrackDos" extension:@"mp3" inBundle:mainBundle] autorelease];
  self.clk = [[self newAudioPlayerForFile:@"Click" extension:@"mp3" inBundle:mainBundle] autorelease];
  self.hs = [[self newAudioPlayerForFile:@"HSSound" extension:@"mp3" inBundle:mainBundle] autorelease];
  [pool release], pool = nil;
}
```

Comment: How would I refactor it to make it look better?

Comment: Ohhh nice, btw it was this line: NSURL *url = [bundle URLForResource:fileName withExtension:extension];
Also is this on a secondary thread so that it will be the most efficient it can be? Edit: Congrats on getting 12K!

Comment: @MyApps That change did not add threading, it was refactoring only. If you also want to try it from a secondary thread, you can use  `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(readySounds)];`, instead of `[self readySounds];`. Then you will have to update `self`'s implementation to be aware of, and respond appropriately to the multithreaded initialization (e.g. it will still be 1.5s until the audio players are all ready, but the UI won't be blocked in the meantime).

Comment: Alright thanks for the info, at this point I don't think I can do much more since I need the sounds ASAP but I just wanted to try my best also to make it look better. So thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the solution to load in the background was a problem... it worked and then the 30th time I used the sound from the main thread all sound stopped working. There are a couple of things that could have happened - I had to create my own autorelease pool and the background thread could have gone away junking the object.

Thinking about it I only have short sound effects - creating the first AVAudioPlayer was slow but the subsequent ones were fine.  So to solve it I created a tiny silent wav file and used that as the first one to load. I used audacity to create the file and did Tracks > Add New > Audio Track, then I did Generate > Silence, picked a very small interval like .01s, then I File > Export'ed the sound and added the file to XCode.

I force the small, silent wav file to load in viewDidLoad and that shortened the lag for me.

Hope this is helpful to someone with a similar problem.